# I am getting an error while trying to run arcore augmented reality in flutter in android virtual device in android studio. How can i fix this

Tags: flutter, android-studio, augmented-reality, android-virtual-device, arcore

when i click run button on android studio app crashes with following error in android studio.i tried changing the OpenGL ES Api level on Android virtual device but it not worked..I appreciate any assistance or insights into this problem. Please let me know if you need more information to assist with debugging. Thank you!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
    Parameter format not correct -
    √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
    Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
    Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54829/f3hHxCxdpnM=/ws
    Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
    I/Filament( 3664): Filament library loaded.
    D/EGL_emulation( 3664): eglCreateContext: 0xf7111ab0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
    D/EGL_emulation( 3664): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf7111ab0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf7478630) (first time)
    E/Filament( 3664): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    I/Filament( 3664): FEngine (32 bits) created at 0xb2e0b030 (threading is enabled)
    D/Filament( 3664): Using ASurfaceTexture
    D/Filament( 3664): FEngine resolved backend: OpenGL
    D/HostConnection( 3664): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf7112990, tid 3709
    D/HostConnection( 3664): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_qsri ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    D/EGL_emulation( 3664): eglCreateContext: 0xf711f8f0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
    D/EGL_emulation( 3664): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf711f8f0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc3e5ea70) (first time)
    I/SceneView( 3664): Optional library com.google.ar.sceneform.animation loaded.
    I/PlatformViewsController( 3664): Hosting view in a virtual display for platform view: 0
    E/EGL_emulation( 3664): eglQueryContext 32c0  EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
    E/EGL_emulation( 3664): tid 3664: eglQueryContext(2019): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
    W/Gralloc4( 3664): allocator 3.x is not supported
    I/Choreographer( 3664): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/OpenGLRenderer( 3664): Davey! duration=700ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=1399901313040, Vsync=1400484646350, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=1400497425755, AnimationStart=1400497426772, PerformTraversalsStart=1400497427266, DrawStart=1400581604560, SyncQueued=1400582200126, SyncStart=1400586204044, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1400586490247, SwapBuffers=1400594245878, FrameCompleted=1400605888737, DequeueBufferDuration=5322886, QueueBufferDuration=805595, GpuCompleted=34359738376, 
    I/com.difrancescogianmarco.arcore_flutter_plugin.utils.ArCoreUtils( 3664): ArCore INSTALL REQUESTED
    I/com.difrancescogianmarco.arcore_flutter_plugin.utils.ArCoreUtils( 3664): ArCore INSTALL REQUESTED
    W/ARCore-InstallService( 3664): bindService returned false.
    W/ARCore-InstallService( 3664): requestInstall bind failed, launching fullscreen.
    D/AndroidRuntime( 3664): Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664): Process: com.example.elibrary_frontend, PID: 3664
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.elibrary_frontend/com.example.elibrary_frontend.MainActivity}: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException: Failed to launch installer.
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4444)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4476)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664): Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException: Failed to launch installer.
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.google.ar.core.u.o(InstallService.java:6)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.google.ar.core.u.d(InstallService.java:10)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity.startInstaller(InstallActivity.java:3)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.google.ar.core.InstallActivity.onResume(InstallActivity.java:3)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8129)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4434)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    ... 11 more
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.ar.core }
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5314)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5272)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5658)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5611)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    at com.google.ar.core.u.o(InstallService.java:5)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3664):    ... 17 more
    I/Process ( 3664): Sending signal. PID: 3664 SIG: 9
    Lost connection to device.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the intial looks of the logs, you are missing [Google Play services for AR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core&pcampaignid=web_share). This needs to be installed on the device.